# Python, re, найти по шаблону

Tags: python, re

Имеется строка `'model1_001234.csv'`. С помощью модуля re стараюсь получить значение int `1234`.

`re.match(r'\d+', 'model1_001234.csv')` почему то выдает `None`, не понимаю почему. Но это все равно не верный подход, потому что перед `'_001234'` стоит еще `'1'`, а это число не нужно.

В итоге хочу в re прописать такую логику - 'ищи любое количество (но не менее одной) цифр после знака _'. Не понимаю как. Помогите пожалуйста, нуб с re.

Comment: match ищет совпадение от начала строки, а чтобы что-то находило в вашей строке по `r'\d+'` вам нужно search. А так, нужно что-то вроде `r"\w+_(\d+)\.\w+"` и вытаскивать group(1) (т.е. то что сматчилось внутри скобок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае сработает такой код:

```py
import re

s = 'model1_001234.csv'

r = []
for m in re.finditer(r'_\d+', s):  # Ищем все символы `_` и цифры за ним
    r.append(int(m.group()[1:]))  # Преобразуем часть без `_` в число

print(r)
```

В списке `r` здесь оказываются все нужные вам числа.

Этот код выводит:

```
[1234]
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте группы:

```py
import re

# После _ ищем одну или более цифр и цифры добавляем в группу 
# чтобы в результате не захватывалось _
regex = r"_(\d+)" 

# Сама строка
string = "model1_001234.csv, model1_001244.csv and model1_002234.csv" 

# Ищем все вхождения и переводим в int
matches = [int(group) for group in re.findall(regex, string)] 

print(matches)
```

Результат:

```
[1234, 1244, 2234]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
txt = 'model1_001234.csv'

print(
    re.search(r'(?<=_)(?:0+)?(\d+)(?=\.)', txt).group(1)
)
```